# Instantiate inside a class its sister class and vice-versa

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, instantiation

Here is my really simple problem in Python:

I have two classes, let say `Dog` and `Cat` inherited from the class `Animal`.
I want at some point, to instantiate a `Cat` inside my `Dog` class, but I'd like as well to instantiate a `Dog` in my `Cat` class.
Here's what my code looks like (split in 3 files) :

```
import animal
import dog

class Cat(animal.Animal):
    def fooCat(self):
        return dog.Dog()
```

_

```
import animal
import cat

class Dog(animal.Animal):
    def fooDog(self):
        return cat.Cat()
```

_

```
class Animal(object):
    pass
```

The code raises an `ImportError` exception because of a loop in the imports. I wasn't able to find a workaround.

I think it should work if my classes are all in the same file, but I'd like to avoid that (my file would then be outrageously big).

Comment: I cannot repeat an `ImportError` with your code, as written. You do have on error, though: `fooCat` and `fooDog` need to accept a `self` argument. Once that is fixed, your code works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it runs fine...

I understand what was the problem. In my actual code, I imported using :
    `from animal import Animal, from cat import Cat, from dog import Dog`
If i just import the filename in the namespace, the exception is not raised. Thanks !

Comment: Also remember in Python there's no requirement for each class to be in its own file: Animal, Cat and Dog can quite happily be put in the same file.